# ANTLR4 grammar don't recognize 20 as NUMBER

Tags: error-handling, antlr4

I have created following grammar(Please, see it bellow) And when I parse following string

> "Schedule;cron(\"*/3 * * * *
>   America/New_York\");'TestFile'yyyy-M-dd-HH-mm;America/New_York;20"

haven an error message

> "line 1:89: mismatched input '20' expecting NUMBER"

.
It's strange, as in my point of view NUMBER:[0-9]+; will allow "20". Where I'm wrong?

Regards,
Vladimir

```
    lexer grammar FileTriggerLexer;

@header { 
 }

STEP
:
    '/' INTEGER
;

SCHEDULE
:
    'Schedule'
;

SEMICOLON
:
    ';'
;

ASTERISK
:
    '*'
;

CRON
:
    'cron'
;

MARKET_CRON
:
    'marketCron'
;

COMBINED
:
    'combined'
;

FILE_FEED
:
    'FileFeed'
;

LBRACKET
:
    '('
;

RBRACKET
:
    ')'
;

PERCENT
:
    '%'
;

INTEGER
:
    [0-9]+
;

MINUTES_INTERVAL
:
    [1-59]
;

HOURS_INTERVAL
:
    [0-23]
;

WEEK_DAYS_INTERVAL
:
    [1-7]
;

MONTH_INTERVAL
:
    [1-12]
;

DAYS_OF_MONTH_INTERVAL
:
    [1-31]
;

DASH
:
    '-'
;

NUMBER
:
    [0-9]+
;



DOUBLE_QUOTE
:
    '"'
;

QUOTE
:
    '\''
;

SLASH
:
    '/'
;

DOT
:
    '.'
;

COMMA
:
    ','
;

UNDERSCORE
:
    '_'
;

ID
:
    [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z0-9]*
; 



REGEX
:
    (
        ID
        | DOT
        | ASTERISK
        | NUMBER
        |PERCENT
    )+
;

WS
:
    [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
; // skip spaces, tabs, newlines

/**
 * Define a grammar called Hello
 */
grammar FileTriggerValidator;

options
   {
    tokenVocab = FileTriggerLexer;
}

r
:
    (schedule
    | file_feed)+
;

expression
:
    schedule
    | file_feed
;

file_feed
:
    file_feed_name SEMICOLON source_file SEMICOLON source_host SEMICOLON
    source_host SEMICOLON regEx SEMICOLON regEx
    (
        SEMICOLON source_host
    )*
;

formatString
:
    source_host
    (
        '%' source_host?
    )* DOT source_host
;

regEx
:
    REGEX
;

source_host
:
    ID
    (
        DASH ID
    )*
;

file_feed_name
:
    FILE_FEED
;

source_file
:
    (
        ID
        | DASH
        | UNDERSCORE
    )+
;

schedule
:
    SCHEDULE SEMICOLON schedule_defining SEMICOLON file_name SEMICOLON timezone

    (
        SEMICOLON NUMBER
    )?
;

schedule_defining
:
    cron
    | market_cron
    | combined_cron
;

cron
:
    CRON LBRACKET DOUBLE_QUOTE cron_part timezone DOUBLE_QUOTE RBRACKET
;

market_cron
:
    MARKET_CRON LBRACKET DOUBLE_QUOTE cron_part timezone DOUBLE_QUOTE COMMA
    DOUBLE_QUOTE ID DOUBLE_QUOTE RBRACKET
;

combined_cron
:
    COMBINED LBRACKET cron_list_element
    (
        COMMA cron_list_element
    )* RBRACKET
;

mic_defining
:
    ID
;

file_name
:
    (
        ID
        | DOT
        | QUOTE
        | DASH
    )+
;

cron_list_element
:
    cron
    | market_cron
;
//

schedule_defined_string
:
    cron
;
// 

cron_part
:
    minutes hours days_of_month month week_days
;
//

minutes
:
    MINUTES_INTERVAL
    | with_step_value
;
//

hours
:
    HOURS_INTERVAL
    | with_step_value
;
//

int_list
:
    INTEGER
    (
        COMMA INTEGER
    )*
;

interval
:
    INTEGER DASH INTEGER
;
//

days_of_month
:
    DAYS_OF_MONTH_INTERVAL
    | with_step_value
;
//

month
:
    MONTH_INTERVAL
    | with_step_value
;
//

week_days
:
    WEEK_DAYS_INTERVAL
    | with_step_value
;
//

timezone
:
    timezone_part
    (
        SLASH timezone_part
    )?
;
//

timezone_part
:
    ID
    (
        UNDERSCORE ID
    )?
;
//

with_step_value
:
    (
        int_list
        | interval
        | ASTERISK
    ) STEP?
;
//
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically made the #1 lexer mistake.

Lexer rules have defined [priority rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267981/3764814), and in your case the `INTEGER` rule takes priority over `NUMBER`. Both have the same definition, therefore you can simply replace all `NUMBER` occurences with `INTEGER` anyway.

Note that your `*_INTERVAL` rules definitions don't mean what you think. For instance `DAYS_OF_MONTH_INTERVAL` (defined as `[1-31]`) will match one digit in the range `1-3`, or `1`, which means it will match either of `1`, `2` or `3`, and nothing else. *And* it is shadowed by the `INTEGER` rule, just like your `NUMBER` rule.

Drop all these `*_INTERVAL` rules, and keep *only* the `INTEGER` rule. Remember that lexing is an independent pass, and the parser has no influence on it. Don't try to validate your cron expressions within the grammar, you'll have a very tough time. First, *parse* your file, and then perform a *separate* validation pass over the result.