# How does the ANTLR lexer disambiguate its rules (or why does my parser produce "mismatched input" errors)?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4, lexer

> **Note:** This is a [self-answered question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) that aims to provide a reference about one of the most common mistakes made by ANTLR users.

---

When I test this very simple grammar:

```
grammar KeyValues;

keyValueList: keyValue*;
keyValue: key=IDENTIFIER '=' value=INTEGER ';';

IDENTIFIER: [A-Za-z0-9]+;
INTEGER: [0-9]+;

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

With the following input:

```
foo = 42;
```

I end up with the following run-time error:

> line 1:6 mismatched input '42' expecting INTEGER
>   line 1:8 mismatched input ';' expecting '='

Why doesn't ANTLR recognize `42` as an `INTEGER` in this case?
It should match the pattern `[0-9]+` just fine.

If I invert the order in which `INTEGER` and `IDENTIFIER` are defined it seems to work, but why does the order matter in the first place?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In ANTLR, the lexer is isolated from the parser, which means it will split the text into *typed* tokens according to the lexer grammar rules, and the parser has no influence on this process (it cannot say *"give me an `INTEGER` now"* for instance). It produces a *token stream* by itself. Furthermore, the parser doesn't care about the token text, it only cares about the token types to match its rules.

This may easily become a problem when several lexer rules can match the same input text. In that case, the token type will be chosen according to these **precedence rules**:

- First, select the lexer rules which match the *longest* input substring
- If the longest matched substring is equal to an implicitly defined token (like `'='`), use the implicit rule as the token type
- If several lexer rules match the same input, choose the *first* one, based on definition order

These rules are very important to keep in mind in order to use ANTLR effectively.

---

In the example from the question, the parser expects to see the following token stream to match the `keyValue` parser rule: `IDENTIFIER` `'='` `INTEGER` `';'` where `'='` and `';'` are implicit token types.

Since `42` can match *both* `INTEGER` and `IDENTIFIER`, and `IDENTIFIER` is defined first, the parser will receive the following input: `IDENTIFIER` `'='` `IDENTIFIER` `';'` which it won't be able to match to the `keyValue` rule. Remember, the parser *cannot* communicate *to* the lexer, it can only receive data from it, therefore it cannot say *"try to match `INTEGER` next"*.

It's advisable to minimize the lexer rules overlap to limit the impact of this effect. In the above example, we have several options:

- Redefine `IDENTIFIER` as `[A-Za-z] [A-Za-z0-9]*` (require it to start with a letter). This avoids the problem entirely but prevents identifier names starting with a number from being defined, so it changes the intent of the grammar.
- Reorder `INTEGER` and `IDENTIFIER`. This solves the problem for most cases, but prevents fully numeric identifiers from being defined, therefore it also changes the intent of the grammar in a subtle, not so obvious way.
- Make the parser accept both token types when lexer rules overlap:
  First, swap `INTEGER` and `IDENTIFIER` in order to give priority to `INTEGER`. Then, define a parser rule `id: IDENTIFIER | INTEGER;` then use that rule instead of `IDENTIFIER` in other parser rules, which would change `keyValue` to `key=id '=' value=INTEGER ';'`.

---

Here's a second lexer behavior example to sum up:

The following combined grammar:

```
grammar LexerPriorityRulesExample;

// Parser rules

randomParserRule: 'foo'; // Implicitly declared token type

// Lexer rules

BAR: 'bar';
IDENTIFIER: [A-Za-z]+;
BAZ: 'baz';

WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Given the following input:

```
aaa foo bar baz barz
```

Will produce the following token sequence from the lexer:

`IDENTIFIER` `'foo'` `BAR` `IDENTIFIER` `IDENTIFIER` `EOF`

- `aaa` is of type `IDENTIFIER`

  Only the `IDENTIFIER` rule can match this token, there is no ambiguity.
- `foo` is of type `'foo'`

  The parser rule `randomParserRule` introduces the implicit `'foo'` token type, which is prioritary over the `IDENTIFIER` rule.
- `bar` is of type `BAR`

  This text matches the `BAR` rule, which is defined *before* the `IDENTIFIER` rule, and therefore has precedence.
- `baz` is of type `IDENTIFIER`

  This text matches the `BAZ` rule, but it also matches the `IDENTIFIER` rule. The latter is chosen as it is defined *before* `BAR`.

  Given the grammar, `BAZ` will never be able to match, as the `IDENTIFIER` rule already covers everything `BAZ` can match.
- `barz` is of type `IDENTIFIER`

  The `BAR` rule can match the first 3 characters of this string (`bar`), but the `IDENTIFIER` rule will match 4 characters. As `IDENTIFIER` matches a longer substring, it is chosen over `BAR`.
- `EOF` (*end of file*) is an implicitly defined token type which always occurs at the end of the input.

As a rule of thumb, specific rules should de defined *before* more generic rules. If a rule can only match an input which is already covered by a previously defined rule, it will *never* be used.

Implicitly defined rules such as `'foo'` act as if they were defined *before* all other lexer rules. As they add complexity, it's advisable to avoid them altogether and declare explicit lexer rules instead. Just having a list of tokens in one place instead of having them scattered across the grammar is a compelling advantage of this approach.

Comment: What should be added here is that implicit lexer tokens should be banned and not be used in an actual grammar. They might be convenient, but add unnecessary trouble. In split grammars they are even flagged as errors.

Comment: @MikeLischke I agree, and have edited the answer accordingly. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski can you please take a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54923203/antlr4-ambiguous-grammar)

Comment: could you please provide an example of the correct grammar in accordance with the question

Comment: @AlexeySh. There are 3 possible solutions to fix the grammar given in the answer (see the bullet points). I'd rather not copy the whole grammar again 3 times.