# ANTLR4 Lexer doesn't like Cisco ACE

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

So, I'm try to parse something like this.

permit 16 any eq 30 www any eq 80 established log-input

The parse tree I'm aiming for looks like this.
[actual output from test rig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2muhA.png)

As you can see, the 16 is my problem. I've nested rules, and it doesn't like it.

The relevant section...

```
ace  : remarks? action source destination ops;
action: ( P | D ) PROTO ;
P : 'permit' ;
D : 'deny' ;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
PROTO : 'ip'
      | 'tcp'
      | 'udp'
      | 'eigrp'
      | 'icmp'
      | NUMBER
      ;
ID : [a-zA-Z-]+ ;
```

If Number is 1st, I get the RED 16, if PROTO is 1st, then all the ports downstream turn RED.

I get that it's just running my LEX rules in order, and they are ambiguous. PROTO can match any number, and so can NUMBER.

However I tried to solve that with nesting them, and fragments, to no avail.

```
ace  : remarks? action source destination ops;
action: ( P | D ) ;
P : 'permit' PROTO;
D : 'deny' PROTO;
NUMBER : [0-9]+ ;
fragment PROTO : 'ip'
      | 'tcp'
      | 'udp'
      | 'eigrp'
      | 'icmp'
      | NUMBER
      ;
ID : [a-zA-Z-]+ ;
```

As soon as I do that, my 'catch-all' ID starts gobbling everything up, and It's still in a tree, but all my token types turn to IDs.

I've looked around this forum, and the gargler for hours, and I haven't seen any way to sort this out, however oddly, the behavior I want is working elsewhere in this same grammar.

```
destination : address ports? ;
address : ADDRESS ADDRESS | HST ADDRESS | ANY ;
ADDRESS : QUAD DOT QUAD DOT QUAD DOT QUAD ;
fragment QUAD : TWO LO5 LO5 | TWO LO4 DIG | ONE DIG DIG | DIG DIG | DIG ;
fragment DOT : '.' ;
fragment ONE : [1] ;
fragment TWO : [2] ;
fragment LO4 : [0-4] ;
fragment LO5 : [0-5] ;
fragment DIG : [0-9] ;
```

That works like a champ, only grabs IPs and host addresses without failure. Of course the 'ports?' section still goes to garbage. However using that same setup, can't seem to grab PORT/PROTOCOL.

I'm missing something fundamental, and after rearranging this thing for far too long... I'm wondering if I should not try and get such specific TOKEN IDs, and handle it in post (aka, with a listener later) or if my tree should contain proper token tags.

** Technically protocols addressed by number should be < 256 so they are a QUAD as I've defined them, but I can't get that working...

Ideas? Suggests? I have the tree, so who cares if it's a number in that spot? I know the parent is action, so the right hand tree being a number should be validated as less than 256 later? I assume the ambiguity is killing it, and if I could redesign this thing removing all ambiguity somehow?

(BTW I'm a self taught novice, so try and speak to me like I have no college education in computer science, I've never read the dragon book, and I've been programming with ANTLR for 4 days... because that is who you're talking to.)

Comment: Yeah, that's the #1 ANTLR misunderstanding - the lexer is totally separated from the parser, read [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267981/3764814).

Comment: I get that the parsing logic is isolated from the lexing logic. I guess I'm not sure why P : 'permit' (PROTO|NUMBER ; doesn't match. I've created a 'longer' rule permit + 16 > permit, or Number individually. I would think P, would match. Yet it doesn't. maybe because i'm ditching the space.. Not sure.

Comment: The issue here is that `PROTO` includes the `NUMBER` alternative but it can never match a `NUMBER`, because `NUMBER` is defined first. Your `action` rule expects `P` `PROTO` but receives `P` `NUMBER` instead.

Comment: I see that in what I posted now, Thank you. Let me ask a different question, a basic simple 3 line lexer...

PERMIT : PER PORT
PORT : [0-9]+
PER : 'permit'

PERMIT will never match... PORT matches, PER matches, but PERMIT will not. I have a LEXER rule PERMIT with a 'longer' match, but does the LONGER match really mean it has to be contiguous characters?

Comment: Yes, tokens are formed of contiguous characters. Your rule would match `permit42` for instance. A parser rule would be a better fit there I think.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread. But hope this helps someone. You can actually use a catch all token to parse most values, and then convert it to more specific values (enums, constants etc) in your visitor/listener code. This is a stripped down example of the grammar that had worked for me

Base Grammar:

```
    lexer grammar Base ;
    
    fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z];
    fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z];
    fragment NUMBER     : [0-9]+;
    fragment WORD       : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | NUMBER | '-' | '_' | '/')+;
    fragment NEWLINE    : '\r' '\n'
        | '\n'
        | '\r';
    
    fragment OBJECT_DESCRIPTION     : ' description';CRLF
        : NEWLINE ;
    
    VALUE
        : (WORD | '.')+ ;
    
    WHITESPACE
        : ' '   -> skip ;
    
    IGNORE
        : .     -> skip ;
```

Access rule grammar:

```
    grammar AccessList;
    
    import Base;
    
    //access-list acl-1 extended permit udp | object network-object-1 eq 123 (source)| 1.1.1.1 ne www (destination)|
    
    accessLists             : (accessListDestination)+;
    accessListDestination   : accessListSource accessListTarget (' rule-id' aclId = VALUE)?;
    accessListSource        : accessListProtocol accessListTarget;
    accessListTarget: (
            ({_input.LT(1).getText().matches("object|object-group")}? objectType = VALUE objectName = VALUE)
            |({_input.LT(1).getText().matches("host")}? host=VALUE ip=VALUE) | ip = VALUE 
        ) accessListPorts?;
    accessListPorts         : (accessListPort | accessListPortRange);
    accessListPortRange     : VALUE startPort=VALUE endPort=VALUE;
    accessListPort          : operatorOrObjectType=VALUE portOrPortGroup=VALUE;
    
    accessListProtocol:
        ACCESS_LIST_KEY name = VALUE accessListType = ACCESS_LIST_TYPE action = VALUE protocol = VALUE accessListInterface?;
    
    accessListInterface: 'ifc' accessListInterfaceName=VALUE;
    
    fragment ACCESS_LIST    : 'access-list';
    fragment EXTENDED       : 'extended';
    fragment ADVANCED       : 'advanced';
```