# antlr4 can't extract literal into token

Tags: antlr4, lexer

I have the following grammar and am trying to start out slowly, working up to move complex arguments.

```
grammar Command;

commands : command+ EOF; 
command : NAME args NL;
args : arg | ;

arg : DASH LOWER | LOWER;
//arg : DASH 'a' | 'x';

NAME : [_a-zA-Z0-9]+;
NL : '\n';
WS : [ \t\r]+ -> skip ; // spaces, tabs, newlines
DASH : '-';
LOWER: [a-z];//'a' .. 'z';
```

I was hoping (for now) to parse files like this:

```
cmd1
cmd3 -a
```

If I run that input through grun I get an error:

```
$ java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Command commands -tree
...
`line 3:6 mismatched input 'a' expecting LOWER`
```

It seems like LOWER should match 'a'. If I change the arg definition to be the commented out line it works fine and I get the '-a' as an arg. What's the difference between using LOWER and using a 'a' explicitly?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267981/3764814)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for writing that up (+1). I ended up with ARG : [-][a-zA-Z0-9]; for the rule, but your other post will help going forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you have a "mismatched" error, add `-tokens` to grun to display the tokens, it helps finding the discrepancy between what you THINK the lexer will do and what it actually DOES. With your grammar :

```
$ alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'
$ grun Command commands -tokens -diagnostics t.text
[@0,0:3='cmd1',<NAME>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='\n',<'
'>,1:4]
[@2,5:8='cmd3',<NAME>,2:0]
[@3,10:10='-',<'-'>,2:5]
[@4,11:11='a',<NAME>,2:6]
[@5,12:12='\n',<'
'>,2:7]
[@6,13:12='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
line 2:6 mismatched input 'a' expecting LOWER
```

you immediately see that the letter `a` is a `NAME`and not the expected `LOWER`.

Also watch rules with an empty alternative :

```
args
    :   arg
    |
    ;
```

may lead to problems in some circumstances. I prefer to explicitly add the `?` suffix which means zero or one time. So my solution would be :

```
grammar Command;

commands
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1829");}
    :   command+ EOF
    ; 

command
    :   NAME args? NL
    ;

args
    :   arg
    ;

arg : DASH? LOWER ;

LOWER : [a-z] ;
NAME  : [_a-zA-Z0-9]+;
DASH  : '-' ;
NL    : '\n' ;
WS    : [ \t\r]+ -> skip ;
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Command commands -tokens -diagnostics t.text
[@0,0:3='cmd1',<NAME>,1:0]
[@1,4:4='\n',<'
'>,1:4]
[@2,5:8='cmd3',<NAME>,2:0]
[@3,10:10='-',<'-'>,2:5]
[@4,11:11='a',<LOWER>,2:6]
[@5,12:12='\n',<'
'>,2:7]
[@6,13:12='<EOF>',<EOF>,3:0]
Question last update 1829
```