# ANTLR C# missing X at X

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I'm using ANTLR with C# to create a simple parser for C-like structs. The runtime version is 4.7.
The grammar looks like this:

```
structDef : STRUCT ID OPENBLOCK (fieldDef)+ CLOSEBLOCK ;
fieldDef : (namespaceQualifier)+ ID ID SEMICOLON ;
namespaceQualifier : ID DOT ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

ID : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
STRUCT : 'struct' ;
NAMESPACE : 'namespace' ;
OPENBLOCK : '{' ;
CLOSEBLOCK : '}' ;
DOT : '.' ;
SEMICOLON : ';' ;
WHITESPACE : (' '|'\t')+ -> skip;
```

Now when I run the parser like this:

```
test = "struct Stest { type name; }"
var lexer = new OdefGrammarLexer(new AntlrInputStream(test));
var tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new OdefGrammarParser(tokenStream);

var ctx = parser.structDef();
Console.Out.WriteLine(ctx.ToString());
```

I get an error output:

```
line 1:0 missing 'struct' at 'struct'
line 1:7 extraneous input 'Stest' expecting '{'
line 1:20 missing '.' at 'name'
line 1:24 mismatched input ';' expecting '.'
```

The first error in the output is particularly interesting, seems that parser fails to find a match where it should. I suspect problems with string locale/encoding, but I'm not sure how to tackle that for ANTLR.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Heh, that's an usual pitfall, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46267980/3764814)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `ID` rule must be after `STRUCT` and `NAMESPACE` rules (any rules that might collide with it), since if an input can match multiple tokens, the one defined first wins
2. `ID` rule should probably be (but perhaps your notation is supported?):

   ```
   ID : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0'..'9' | '_')* ;
   ```

Comment: FWIW, OP's notation is supported.