# Ambiguous Lexer rules in Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have an antlr grammar with multiple lexer rules that match the same word. It can't be resolved during lexing, but with the grammar, it becomes unambiguous.

Example:

```
conversion: NUMBER UNIT CONVERT UNIT;
NUMBER: [0-9]+;
UNIT: 'in' | 'meters' | ......;
CONVERT: 'in';
```

Input: `1 in in meters`

The word "in" matches the lexer rules `UNIT` and `CONVERT`.

How can this be solved while keeping the grammar file readable?

Answer (score 3):

When an input matches two lexer rules, ANTLR chooses either the longest or the first, see [disambiguate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267980/how-does-the-antlr-lexer-disambiguate-its-rules-or-why-does-my-parser-produce). With your grammar, `in` will be interpreted as `UNIT`, never `CONVERT`, and the rule

```
conversion: NUMBER UNIT CONVERT UNIT;
```

can't work because there are three `UNIT` tokens :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics input.txt 
[@0,0:0='1',<NUMBER>,1:0]
[@1,1:1=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:1]
[@2,2:3='in',<UNIT>,1:2]
[@3,4:4=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:4]
[@4,5:6='in',<UNIT>,1:5]
[@5,7:7=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:7]
[@6,8:13='meters',<UNIT>,1:8]
[@7,14:14='\n',<NL>,1:14]
[@8,15:14='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
Question last update 0159
line 1:5 missing 'in' at 'in'
line 1:8 mismatched input 'meters' expecting <EOF>
```

What you can do is to have only `ID` or `TEXT` tokens and distinguish them with a label, like this :

```
grammar Question;

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 0132");}
    :   conversion NL EOF
    ;

conversion
    :   NUMBER unit1=ID convert=ID unit2=ID
        {System.out.println("Quantity " + $NUMBER.text + " " + $unit1.text +
         " to convert " + $convert.text + " " + $unit2.text);}
    ;

ID      : LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT | '_' )* ; // or TEXT : LETTER+ ;     
NUMBER  : DIGIT+ ;

NL      : [\r\n] ;
WS      : [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN) ; // -> skip ;

fragment LETTER : [a-zA-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT  : [0-9] ;
```

Execution :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics input.txt 
[@0,0:0='1',<NUMBER>,1:0]
[@1,1:1=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:1]
[@2,2:3='in',<ID>,1:2]
[@3,4:4=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:4]
[@4,5:6='in',<ID>,1:5]
[@5,7:7=' ',<WS>,channel=1,1:7]
[@6,8:13='meters',<ID>,1:8]
[@7,14:14='\n',<NL>,1:14]
[@8,15:14='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
Question last update 0132
Quantity 1 in to convert in meters
```

Labels are available from the rule's context in the visitor, so it is easy to distinguish tokens of the same type.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the info in your question, it's hard to say what the best solution would be - I don't know what your lexer rules *are*, for example - nor can I tell why you have lexer rules that are ambiguous at all.

In my experience with antlr, lexer rules don't generally carry any semantic meaning; they are just text that matches some kind of regular expression.  So, instead of having `VARIABLE`, `METHOD_NAME`, etc, I'd just have `IDENTIFIER`, and then figure it out at a higher level.

In other words, it seems (from the little I can glean from your question) that you might benefit either from replacing `UNIT` and `CONVERT` with grammar rules, or just having a single rule:

```
conversion: NUMBER TEXT TEXT TEXT
```

and validating the text values in your ANTLR listener/tree-walker/etc.

**EDIT**

Thanks for updating your question with lexer rules.  It's clear now *why* it's failing - as BernardK points out, antlr will always choose the first matching lexer rule.  This means it's impossible for the second of two ambiguous lexer rules to match, and makes your proposed design infeasible.

My opinion is that lexer rules are not the correct layer to do things like unit validation; they excel at structure, not content.  Evaluating the parse tree will be much more practical than trying to contort an antlr grammar.

Finally, you might also do something with embedded actions on parse rules, like validating the value of an ID token against a known set of units.  It could work, but would destroy the reusability of your grammar.

Comment: I added the lexer rules to the example to make it more clear. Catching all text in a lexer rule and parsing it manually in the visitor defeats the purpose of using Antlr. Moving the lexer rules to grammar rules would work, but would make the grammar hard to read: `unit: 'm' 'e' 't' 'e' 'r' | ... `