# ANTLR4 ambiguous grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to achieve following behavior: `User:class` should be parsed to `Object - User; Type - class`, also`Us:er:class` should result `Object - Us:er; Type - class`. I can't make second part work, as soon as I add `:` as a legal symbol for `WORD` it parses whole input as an object `Object - Us:er:class`.
 My grammar:

```
grammar Sketch;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */
input               : (object)+ EOF ;
object              : objectName objectType? NEWLINE ;
objectType          : ':' TYPE ;
objectName          : WORD ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */ 
fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
fragment NUMBER     : [0-9] ;
fragment WHITESPACE : (' ') ;
fragment SYMBOLS    : [!-/:-@[-`] ;
fragment C          : [cC] ;
fragment L          : [lL] ;
fragment A          : [aA] ;
fragment S          : [sS] ;
fragment T          : [tT] ;
fragment U          : [uU] ;
fragment R          : [rR] ;

TYPE                : ((C L A S S) | (S T R U C T));

NEWLINE             : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+ ;

WORD                : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | NUMBER | WHITESPACE | SYMBOLS)+ ;
```

Fragments for each letter are for case-insensitive parsing.
As I understand, lexer gives priority to rules top-to-bottom, so TYPE should be picked over WORD, but I can't achieve it.
I'm new to antlr4, maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I made the mistake of using a '-' (minus) symbol in a character set '[]' - where it is not interpreted as a literal character but as a range operator (just like you use in UPPERCASE etc). So I would escape it with a back slash: '\-' in SYMBOL.
Perhaps the ':' also has a special meaning? [2c]

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to parse something so simple you do not need to write a parser with ANTLR. It is one of the very few cases where I would suggest just using a simple regex.
If you want to solve it with ANTLR I would do it like this:
1) Ugly solution: you try to use predicates or actions to trick & force the parsing to do what you want
2) You simply define two tokens: one to get identifiers and one to get the semicolon. Then you do the composition later, in the code using your parser.

For example, for `User:class` you would get [[ID:"User"], [ID:"class"]]
while for `Us:er:class` you would get [[ID:"Us"], [ID:"er"], [ID:"class"]]
then you code you know that the last ID represent the type and the sequence of all the other IDs represent the object.

Neither are not great solutions but I think ANTLR is not the right tool for what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is just simple example, in fact I have more complicated grammar. I'm trying to solve it using nongreedy operators. In theory it should work, but I didn't manage it yet.